# Unit Test Culture error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I want to perform a unit test to this library I've built but when I try to build the solution, it fails. I do not touch the Culture in any way and I've tried to look at the code in the Microsoft.Common.targets but I simply can't figure out what the problem might be.

The exact error is as follows:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CardTests, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Build started 14-12-2013 15:14:41.
1>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): error MSB3095: Invalid argument. Culture is not supported.
1>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): error MSB3095: Parameter name: name
1>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): error MSB3095: en-UK is an invalid culture identifier.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.02
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the test I perform:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Game;

namespace CardTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Deck d = new Deck();

            Console.WriteLine(d.GetCard().ToString());

            d.Shuffle();

            int i = 1;
            foreach (Card c in d.GetCards(10))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + ".: " + c.ToString());
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you double click on the compile error, where does VS take you?

Comment: @rhughes, the error doesn't contain any line number of file name, except to the `Microsoft.Common.targets`, so there is no direct link to the source file that causes this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that it was the AssemblyCulture of the library (which I never changed) that was the problem.

Comment: So, how were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This can have multiple causes...

- a resouce file with the `Resource.{culture}.resx` name with an invalid format
- a [`NeutralResourcesLanguages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs that's incorrect
- an [`AssemblyCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblycultureattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute in your code, this attribute should be added by the compiler, not in your own code.
- referencing a satilite assembly (`assembly.{culture}.dll`) instead of the base assembly.